# Using php and javascript to put random number in txt file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a text input field with a button that generates a random number between 1 and 20 and displays within the text field. The problem I am having, is taking that random number that it generates and saving it into a .txt file. The file chat.txt is stored in the same directory as the rest of these files. Not sure I am going about this the right way. The following is the code. Any ideas would be helpful.

chat.php:

```
<div id="pageWrap">
<form action="roll.php" name="rollBox" method="post">
<input type="text" name="roll" id="demo">
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="myFunction()">Roll</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("demo")
x.value=Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
}
</script>

<h2>Chat</h2>
    <p id="name-area"></p>
    <div id="chatWrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>

    <form id="send-message-area">
        <p>Your message: </p>
        <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '100' ></textarea>
    </form>

</div>
```

roll.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
    $roll = $_POST['roll'];
    $file = fopen("chat.txt");
    fwrite($file,$roll);
    fclose($file); 
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in your way of generating random number on client end with javascript:

on html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pageWrap">
    <form action="page.php" id="rollBox" name="rollBox" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="roll" id="demo">

        <button type="submit" name="submit" >Roll</button>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#rollBox').submit(function(e) {
                var x=document.getElementById("demo");
                x.value=Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
                e.preventDefault();
                var obj = $(this), // (*) references the current object/form each time
                url = obj.attr('action'),
                method = obj.attr('method'),
                data = {};
                obj.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
                    var obj = $(this),
                    name = obj.attr('name'),
                    value = obj.val();
                    data[name] = value;
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: method,
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response2) {}
                });
                return false; 
            });
        });
        function myFunction()
        {
            var x=document.getElementById("demo")
            x.value=Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
            document.getElementById("rollBox").submit();
        }
        </script>
    </form>
    <h2>Chat</h2>
    <p id="name-area"></p>
    <div id="chatWrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>

    <form id="send-message-area">
        <p>Your message: </p>
        <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '100' ></textarea>
    </form>

</div>
```

on php change this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))//on submit
{
//echo 'here';
    $roll = $_POST['roll'];
    $file = fopen("chat.txt","w");//no mode selected
    fwrite($file,$roll);
    fclose($file); 
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
?>
```

This works and generates the chat.txt

Comment: yah,why? any mistakes i made? :(

Comment: A form within a form is invalid html.

Comment: that html was from him, i know that but I think that second form wont work if he doesn't close the first one.

Comment: yah sure,edited it. didnt see it in the first place though,but it worked alright.

Comment: So this worked. A couple issues, which i also had with scrblnrd3's answer. First off, it should append the file (sorry I should have mentioned that before), rather than clear the file. Not sure how to make your code append. The other issue is, I need it to stay on the same page without refresh, is that still doable?

Comment: $file = fopen("chat.txt","a"); for append. Thats doable with ajax call (for your 2nd request)

Comment: @Aldentec It is with ajax.  Do you have anything against jquery?

Comment: Ok I had a feeling it would be with ajax. Any point in the right direction would be good. Sorry I am still a beginner.

Comment: jquery would be fine too.

Comment: yah will do,actually use like this $('#rollBox').submit(function(e) {} ); answer accpeted?

Comment: @GunnerAziz Yes and no; you left out quiet a bit, I'd recommend you edit your answer with the correct information.

Comment: I added $('#rollBox').submit(function(e) {} ); into the header as I assumed it should be? Didn't help so I assume I am doing something wrong./

Comment: @Aldentec Yes, and no.  As stated above, Gunner left out quite a bit.  While I could easily answer this question, at the moment I'm choosing not to, to give Gunner a chance.

Comment: @Daedalus Ok no problem. I greatly appreciate your guys' help.

Comment: @GunnerAziz Ok this is way awesome, it is adding into the txt file and displays. One last thing maybe you can help me with this, if not it's cool you have already been a huge help. But when I submit the form for the random number, it displays the first submit. But does not display any more after that. I would like for it to be able to display each random number every time i press submit. 

Again, do not worry if you do not want to try and figure that one out, as I am sure I can get it eventually (hopefully) but any more of your insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: please see the new page.php, I left an echo uncommented. Answer accepted(if it works right :D)?

Comment: @GunnerAziz Thank you so much. I realized the last issue I mentioned was actually a result of some other code I had. You have absolutely answered my questions and then some. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The random number is only generated on the client side: you're not sending it to the server yet. You're starting a form (`name=rollbox`), which you not sending back to the server (also you seem to be missing a `</form>`. Either submit the form, or use AJAX to send the information to the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just generate the random number in PHP, and then put it in the file with `file_put_contents()`like this?

```
<?php
    $roll = rand(1,20);
    file_put_contents("chat.txt",$roll);


?>
```

Comment: OK that worked to get the number in the txt file. However now it clears out the previous contents of the txt file. Any idea on how to get it to just add to the file? One more thing (and sorry for the newbie questions) but when I submit the form with the file_put_contents, it then goes to the page roll.php Any way of keeping it on the same page without refreshing?

Comment: Ok I figured out that FILE_APPEND will add the content, rather than replacing existing content. My issue now is just keeping it on the same page, rather than the form re-directing to roll.php

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with the HTML of your top FORM.

Try replace it with the following code:

```
<form action="roll.php" name="rollBox" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="roll" id="demo">
   <input type="submit" name="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="Roll">
</form>
```